# Best way to add computed sub document to array on Document creation in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider:

```
const memberInfo = new Schema({
  idMember: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'member', requied: true },
  memberType: {
    type: String,
    default: 'normal',
    enum: ['normal', 'admin', 'owner'],
  },
});

const boardSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  idMemberCreator: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'member',
    required: true,
  },
  members: [memberInfo],
});
```

When I create a new board with the "name" and "idMemberCreator" field, I would like the model to automatically add a "memberInfo" subdocument to the "members" array with the "idMember" field being set to "idMemberCreator" and the "memberType" being set to "owner".

Is there a way to do this? I want to handle this within the schema if possible, and not have to save that field in the controller/resolver function.

Answer (score 0):

use mongoose hook

```
boardSchema.post('save', function() {
  this.update({},{ $push: { members: {idMember:"$idMemberCreator",memberType:"owner"} } });
});
```